# eclipse: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject driving me bananas?

Tags: eclipse

Hell folks, i have eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 1 Build id: 20100917-0705. 
Does someone know how to get rid of this nasty exception?

I've tried with a brand new indigo installation, brand new tomcat 7.0.22, to no avail, what could be wrong with my project?

I'm using geotools.

---

Ok, I somewhat found the cause. When I use Geotools' `DataStoreFinder.getDataStore()` method the exception shows up. if I use other methods everything's fine.

What puzzles me, and the main reason to ask this question here, is because one would expect other kind of exception, like a geotools exception, but, why an eclipse exception? however, if someone finds ever the reason, I'll be more than glad to listen about it.

if you want to replicate it, these are the steps to follow:

- download geotools (exception 'works' with vers 2.7 and 8)
- eclipse indigo or helios
- apache tomcat 6 or 7
- jdk 1.6
- create a simple servlet and just call `DataStoreFinder.getDataStore()` inside the `doget` or `dopost` method.

Comment: What are you trying to do that causes this exception?

Comment: below i posted all the details

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but sounds like you don't have EMF installed and Geotools must depend on it. EObject is the EMF base class. If you used p2 to install Geotools though, it should have made sure that EMF was already installed. If however you just copied the plugins for it into your Eclipse installation and did not have EMF, you would see this.